# counting new data from database using Codeigniter 2.1.4

Tags: codeigniter

### Counting New Data

---

How to counting new data in database on codeigniter, i want to create notification using codeigniter for restaurant system..

Comment: what do you mean by New Data? Describe more about what you want and what you have tried?

Comment: it's data about restaurant, and i want to add notification in every order in page ordering...

Comment: Do You mean by real time Notification?

Comment: yes, read according to the latest time

Comment: Do some research on Server Real Time Response( Server PUSH Event ) or use ajax as an alternative to send request after specific time of duration to check for order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax on the concerned web page to call a web service at set intervals (say 3 seconds) which returns whether any new entry has been made.

Comment: yes, i've using ajax.. but i confused to read last data.. how to parsing new data order by time..

Comment: how are you confused and what have you tried exactly?

Comment: well, if this is the answer you needed, then you should probably select it as the best answer